# Check if two Colliders overlap with Raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, raycasting

Trying to detect if an object is overlapping with another object by using a Raycast Sphere with little or no distance. My relevant code is as follows:

```
//Check at location using Stationary Spherecast, apply damage effect if its a unit
        if (Physics.SphereCast (transform.position, 3, Vector3.up, out hit, 1)) {
            Debug.Log ("In Spherecast");
            if (hit.transform.CompareTag ("Enemy unit") || hit.transform.CompareTag ("Player Unit")) {
                Debug.Log ("In Spherecast's If");
                int Dmg = MM.MoveStat (Ours, SM.selected.GetComponent<EidolonClass> (), hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<EidolonClass> ());
                hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<EidolonClass> ().TakeDamage (Dmg);
            }
        }
```

At present, however, neither of those Debug.Log statements ever get output to the console. Is there something I'm misunderstanding about the spherecast, or about its constructors?

Comment: Does Debug.Log work if you put it outside the top level if statement?

Comment: Yes, its contained within another function. Putting a Debug.log just before the first if or just after it both work

Comment: What if you set the radius and maxDistance very high?  Does "In Spherecast" ever get printed?

Comment: `Raycast` and `SphereCast` generally don't return hits for overlapping colliders. Would `OverlapSphere` meet your needs, instead?

Comment: Nope, Still not called.

Comment: I havent seen OverlapSphere before, ill need a minute to read into it.

Comment: Note that a SphereCast won't normally hit an object if the object if the object is already inside the spherical area when the SphereCast starts, which is probably why your original code was failing.

Answer (score 3):

> Trying to detect if an object is overlapping with another object

Use one of the [`Physics.OverlapXXX`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html) functions. There are many of them but if Sphere is what you are looking for then `Physics.OverlapSphere` should be used.

For the sake of performance, use the ones that ends with `NonAlloc`.

`Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc` should be fine for this. Just check if what it returns is > `0`.

```
Collider[] colliders = new Collider[5];

void Update()
{
    if (Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(transform.position, 3, colliders) > 0)
    {
       //Overlaps!
    }
}
```

**Note**:

Make sure that a collier is attached to both GameObjects you want to check of they overlap with one another.

**EDIT**:

If you need to access the `Colliders` too:

```
Collider[] colliders = new Collider[5];

void Update()
{
    int hitCount = Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(transform.position, 3, colliders);

    if (hitCount > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Touching!");

        for (int i = 0; i < hitCount; i++)
        {
            Collider C = colliders[i];

            Debug.Log("In Foreach for: " + C.name.ToString());
            if (C.transform.CompareTag("Enemy Unit"))
            {
                Debug.Log(C.name.ToString() + " Is an enemy");

                //...
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Not Touching!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get this implementation to work either. I'm going to try to see if the two objects aren't intersecting for some other reason Edit: They're definitely overlapping, as confirmed with Debug.Drawrays sticking out of the object i need it to collide with, the if simply isnt working

Comment: Another possible problem is the position you are passing it. Are you sure you are passing it the right position? If you do all these right it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding a solution that worked, taking ideas from the solutions Programmer and rutter suggested, as welll as looking around both on this site and on the official Unity Forums to find a solution that did what I needed. Heres the finished segment of code:

```html
Collider[] collisions = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position,.75f);
  foreach (Collider C in collisions) {
   Debug.Log("In Foreach for: " + C.name.ToString());
   if (C.transform.CompareTag ("Enemy Unit")) {
    Debug.Log (C.name.ToString () + " Is an enemy");
    int Dmg = MM.MoveStat (Ours, SM.selected.GetComponent<EidolonClass> (), C.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<EidolonClass> ());
    C.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<EidolonClass> ().TakeDamage (Dmg);
   }
  }
```